# How to store all editable values in an array using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $("#fieldset").closest("fieldset").find("input, select,textarea").change(function() {
        return ($(this).val());
    }).get().join(',');
```

I am getting all editable field values on change.. I need to store all editable values in an array to pass to the controller?

how to store the values in an array

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array;

$("#fieldset").change(function(event) {
    $(event.target).data('changed',true);
});

$("form").submit(function() {
    array = $(this).find("input, select,textarea").map(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if( $th.data('changed') ) return $(this).val();
    }).get();
});
```

The `#fieldset` change event will fire when any of its descendant elements are changed.

Then handler finds the input/select/textarea elements, and performs `.map()` on them returning their value, which creates a jQuery object with the values.

`.get()` grabs/returns the array from the jQuery object.

**Test it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mrrty/2/ *(change the value of one of the elements)*

- http://api.jquery.com/map/
- http://api.jquery.com/get/

---

**EDIT:**

Note that if you don't want to get a new array *every* time one of the elements changes, you can do the same thing with a different event. Perhaps doing this on `.submit()` would be more appropriate.

- http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Thanks..patrick..I need to have this condition.. if any changes are made fieldset I need to pass array if not I need to pass null value?
how to check the condition?

Comment: @rockers - What is triggering this? Is it a `submit()`?

Comment: @rockers - You didn't respond to my comment, so I went ahead and updated my answer after seeing your other question.

Comment: Sorry pat I was away my desk.. yes your logic working for me.